# How to put arrays as csv columns in shell?

Tags: regex, shell, csv, grep, export-to-csv

I'm trying to write a shell script that look for a string in the output of my program (through regular expression) and save the string that matches that regular expression in a variable for further use.

For example:

```
output = ./test --sd --sdds 200
re='K=[*]'
if (found a match of re in output)
  print getMatchedStringIfExists(output)
if not exists
  do something else
```

So, basically I wanna run my program, after finishes, check if the program outputted "re='K=[*]'", if so, returns that string that matches (e.g. K=[1,2,3,4,54]), otherwise do something else.

I just want a basic explanation how can I do that in shell script, if it's possible, of course.

Thanks in advance!

**NOTE:**
I got what I needed:

```
output = $(./test --sd --sdds 200 | grep -o 'K=\[.*.\]')
if [$output != ""]
then
  $_out = "SUCCESFUL"
else
   $_out = "FAILED"
fi
```

I still can't save in a .csv file. I have 4 arrays and I need to put in columns of a csv file. Anyone know to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

A websearch for "shell scripting tutorial" (or "bash tutorial" if that's the particular shell you are using) will return many explanations.

For example:

- https://www.shellscript.sh/
- https://www.bash.academy/
- https://www.learnshell.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the `if` directly, like this:

```
if ./test --sd --sdds 200 | egrep 'K=\[.*\]' &>/dev/null; then
    # do whatever
else
    # do something else
fi
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for. I tried a simple example in ter terminal here like `ls -l | egrep 't*\.py' &>/dev/null` and it didn't return a thing, and should return, in this case, the string `test.py`....I want to store that value in a variable for further use in a csv file.